# Getting the values() of an enum when the enum is declared as a generic parameter

Tags: java, generics, enums

The code shown below does work because the method `values()` is static. My question is how can I achieve what the code below would do if B was not generic.

```
class A<B extends Enum<B>> {
    public A() {
        for (B b : b.values()) {

        }
    }
}
```

I can think of two solutions:

1. pass the enum values into A's constructor
2. make B implement an interface that defines a method for obtaining the enum values.

Both seem messy to me. Anyone have any better solutions?

Comment: `enum B {} ... for (B b: B.values()) { ... }`?

Comment: @Joop Eggen - huh? Like I said in the question values() is static and therefore has to be accessed statically. So your suggestion won't work due to type erasure.

Comment: The call B.values is static, as B is the class; a class object is "static". (It is not b.values.)

Comment: @JoopEggen: that doesn't answer this problem. A is generic and can take any enum as type parameter. B is not fixed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [getEnumConstants()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29)

Comment: +1: This still requires the `B` class to be available at runtime.

Comment: So, what your're suggesting is that A's constructor should be modified to as follows: public A(Class<B> clazzB) { for (B b : clazzB.getEnumConstants()); } ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stripped-down example involving a subclass of JPanel that let's you choose a value from an Enum using radio buttons. To use it you'd do something like:

```
enum Animal { DOG, CAT, FISH };
RadioPanel<Animal> animal_panel = new RadioPanel<Animal>(Animal.class);
dialog.add(animal_panel);
...
Animal favorite_animal = animal_panel.getSelectedOption();
```

The class itself:

```
public class RadioPanel<T extends Enum<T>> extends JPanel {
    private Map<T,JRadioButton> buttons;
    private ButtonGroup button_group;
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public RadioPanel(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        buttons = new EnumMap<T, JRadioButton>(clazz);
        button_group = new ButtonGroup();       

        for (T value : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
            JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton(value.toString());
            buttons.put(value, button);
            button_group.add(button);
            add(button);
        }
    }

    public void setSelectedOption(T value) {
        buttons.get(value).setSelected(true);
    }

    public T getSelectedOption() {
        for (T value : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
            if (buttons.get(value).isSelected())
                return value;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```